# Python split function not working in while loop

Tags: python

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to pull the elements out of a text file that has the format [a b c d e...] into a list, and using split() to do this. This seems to work perfectly when outside the while loop, and the printed variable displays

```
 ['2016-2017', '1', '1', '1', '4', '1', '2', '2', '1', '0', '1', '1', '3', '1', '5', '0', '3', 
  '2', '4', '4', '2', '4', '2', '0', '1', '0', '4', '3', '2', '2', '3', '4', '4', '1', '2', 
  '0', '2', '6', '7']
```

which is exactly what I want. However, when I try to do this in the while loop using split(), I get an infinite loop of empty lists. I've tried removing split() from the loop and that prints

```
2017-2018 2 1 1 3 0 3 4 1 4 0 1 0 1 1 1 5 2 1 3 5 2 1 4 1 2 2 1 1 2 4 3 2 1 1 2 0 1 5
```

for all lines in the file, but I want it to look like the first printed variable.

My code for reference:

```
with open(HOTSPUR, 'r') as infile:
    goals_line = infile.readline().strip().split()
    print(goals_line)
    
    while goals_line != '':
        goals_line = infile.readline().strip().split()
        print(goals_line)
```

Comment: I suggest adding `print()` statements to your code to follow the execution. You can print messages like `"HERE"` or `"before loop"` just to indicate where you are.

Answer (score 4):

`goals_line` is a list so will never compare to `''`.  As you stated, you eventually get empty lists (`[]`) so you could check for that.  But a better solution is to loop through the lines of the file:

```py
with open(HOTSPUR) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        goals_line = line.strip().split()
        print(goals_line)
```

Comment: Oh! That definitely makes sense but I can't translate it in my head to a while loop (I have to use while loops for this assignment). Would I have to set the first line as goals_line = infile.readline() before entering the while loop and not make it into a list by using split()?

Comment: @jo Yes, only make it a list after you know the `.readline()` was not empty.  Always makes me cringe when a teacher makes students write code that no good programmer would really use.